# Adding Angular MatDialog in existing app prevents page scrolls

Tags: angular, angular-material, scrollview

I added angular material MatDialog to show model window which accepts Form data from the user.

I added this in app.scsss file

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

Now the model opens when clicking on the button but the entire window has no more scrolls available in app in each of the components.

I think this happens whenever i add any angular material component into my existing app,that it stops scrolling.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Remove node_modules
Step 2: npm install

Fixed an issue.